# How to upgrade to Windows 8 with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS already there in Dual Boot Settings

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am using a Dell Inspiron 15R 7520 SE laptop which came with Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium. I followed these links to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in dual boot configuration :

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/09/18/guide-to-disks-and-disk-partitions-in-linux/

I also used Easy BCD so that whenever my laptop would start, the Windows Boot Loader would ask me to choose whether i wanted to boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu. Worked fine.

How do I upgrade to Windows 8 in Custom Install mode where all my Windows 7 Data will vanish, without affecting Ubuntu and the Dual boot settings?

I first tried on my own and ended up messing my laptop quite a bit.